# Unable to format calculated slider min and max values to reduce decimal places

Tags: r, shiny, format, slider

I can not find any documentation on how to format slider values from dynamic data.  I've tried to wrap "dollar" and "dollar_format" around the slider range values, but it bombs out on me.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel(title = "Test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("NewData", "Upload File", multiple = FALSE, accept = ".xlsx") 

    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      
      tabsetPanel( type = "tabs", #Open panel
                   tabPanel("Distributions 1",plotOutput("hist1.plot")
                            ,uiOutput("updaterange")
                            )
                   
      ),
      tabsetPanel( type = "tabs", #Open panel
                   tabPanel("Distributions 2",plotOutput("hist2.plot")
                            #,uiOutput("update_mod_hist_range")
                            )
      )
      
    ) # close mainPanel
  ) # close sidebarLayout
) # close fluidPage


server <- function(input,output){ 
  
  ev = reactiveValues()
  
  
  observeEvent(input$NewData,{
    if(is.null(input$NewData))
      return(NULL)
    
    ev$sim.data <- read_excel(input$NewData$datapath)
    req(ev$sim.data)
    
    amount = c(sapply(ev$sim.data$amt,function(x){runif(1000,1,x)}))
    
    cat = (rep(ev$sim.data$cat, each = 1000))
    
    hist.data = data.frame(amount,cat)
    names(hist.data) = c("amount","cat")
    hist.data$cat = factor(hist.data$cat, levels = c("a","b","c"))
    
    low = mean(hist.data$amount)-sd(hist.data$amount)
    high = mean(hist.data$amount) + sd(hist.data$amount)
    
    ev$low = low
    ev$high = high
    ev$hist.data <- hist.data
    
    output$updaterange = renderUI({

      sliderInput("update_mod_hist_range","Update this Histogram",
                  min = min(ev$hist.data$amount),
                  max = max(ev$hist.data$amount),
                  value = c(ev$low,ev$high)
      )
    })
    
    
    pricedata = ddply(hist.data, c("cat"), plyr::summarize, avg = mean(amount), minus.stdev = mean(amount)-sd(amount),
                      plus.stdev = mean(amount) + sd(amount))
    pricedata = pricedata[order(pricedata$avg),]
    
    output$hist1.plot = renderPlot({
      
      ggplot(subset(hist.data, cat!="" ), 
             aes(x=amount, fill = cat))+
        geom_histogram(color="white", alpha = .8, position = 'identity', binwidth = 5)+
        theme_test()+
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = avg), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = 1)+
        
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = minus.stdev), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = .75, linetype = "dotted")+
        
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = plus.stdev), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = .75, linetype = "dotted")+
        
        facet_grid(cat ~., scales = "free")+
        scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),name = "Count")+
        scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar, name="\nAmount", limits = c(0,100))
      
    }) #close renderPlot
    
  })

  observeEvent(input$update_mod_hist_range,{
    if(is.null(input$update_mod_hist_range)) return(NULL)
    
    mod.amount = runif(1000,input$update_mod_hist_range[1],input$update_mod_hist_range[2])
    
    #mod.amount = runif(1000,ev$low,ev$high)
    
    
    cat = rep("x",1000)
    mod.hist.data = data.frame(mod.amount,cat)
    names(mod.hist.data) = c("amount","cat")
    
    #mod.hist.data$cat = factor(mod.hist.data$cat, levels = c("a","b","c"))
    pricedata2 = ddply(mod.hist.data, c("cat"), plyr::summarize, avg = mean(amount), minus.stdev = mean(amount)-sd(amount),
                       plus.stdev = mean(amount) + sd(amount))
    pricedata2 = pricedata2[order(pricedata2$avg),]
    output$hist2.plot = renderPlot({ # open renderPlot
      
      ggplot(mod.hist.data, aes(x=amount))+
        geom_histogram(color="white", alpha = .8, position = 'identity', binwidth = 5)+
        theme_test()+
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = avg), data = pricedata2, color = "black", size = 1)+
        
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = minus.stdev), data = pricedata2, color = "black", size = .75, linetype = "dotted")+
        
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = plus.stdev), data = pricedata2, color = "black", size = .75, linetype = "dotted")+
        
        #facet_grid(cat ~., scales = "free")+
        scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),name = "Count")+
        scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar, name="\nAmount", limits = c(0,100))
      
    }) #close renderPlot
  
  
})
 
     
} # close shinyServer

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Input file is excel (can't attach file):

```
a1 = amt
a2 = 50
a3 = 60
a4 = 70
b1 = cat
b2 = a
b3 = b
b4 = c
```

you can see in the picture below the min and max values have lots of trailing decimals.

[image: slider pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occurring because you are setting the sliders min and max to values with lots of digits after the decimal point. You can solve this by rounding the values for the sliders min and max first, for example:

```
sliderInput("update_mod_hist_range","Update this Histogram",
    min = floor(min(ev$hist.data$amount)),
    max = ceiling(max(ev$hist.data$amount)),
    value = c(ev$low,ev$high)
)
```

`floor` rounds numbers down, and `ceiling` rounds numbers up.